# Visual Studio 2015 add JSON-File

Tags: json, visual-studio

I have a WebApplication MVC Porject. In the folder App_Data i want to add a json-file.
But Visual Studio does not suggest me to add a Json-File even not if i want to add a new Element.

[image]

How can I add a json? Just to use a normal text file and rename it as json?

Answer (score 6):

You can find it under Web. Consider using the search-bar top right if you can't find something, if it does not show up in search you wont be able to do it.

JSON:

[image]

Comment: For me the Web or any subitem under Web shows only "Please choose a project type" and no file types are listed at all. Sigh...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would just change the file extension to .json
[Adding Product.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuZWW.png)